Pullback/Pushout Diagrams
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a pointed infinity category. I need to show that (this spaces has all finite limits and colimits and that every commutative diagram is pullback iff its a pushout) if and only if this space has pushouts and pullbacks of certain sort and that all commutative diagrams of that sort are pullbacks iff it is a pushout diagram. With of certain sort I mean that we have the basepoint in the diagram, i.e for pushouts like this  $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
x_0 @>{}>> C
\end{CD}
and for pullback diagrams like this:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
x_0 @>{}>> Y
\end{CD}
Moreover I need to show that this is not fullfilled for the category of all Anima.
I mean the first direction is trivial, but if I know that this statements are true only for this certain diagrams how can I follow this for general pushouts and pullbacks?

If you have a pullback diagram
$$\begin{CD}
x @>>> x^{\prime}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
y @>{}>> y^{\prime},
\end{CD}$$
you can extend this to a diagram (you should interpret this as being defined on $\Delta^2\times\Delta^1$)
$$\begin{CD}
a @>>> x @>>> y\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\ast @>>> y @>>> y^{\prime},
\end{CD}$$
so that $\ast$ is the zero object and the left square is a pullback square. It follows by pasting that the outer square also is a pullback square. Then, the assumption guarantees that the left and outer square are pushout squares. The pasting lemma in turn implies that the right square is a pushout square. The converse direction is proved analogously.

what is a in your extension?

@user1072285 It's determined by saying the left square is a pullback square.

ah yes this was not a good question. But another doubt, I understand now how to show, that push outs and pullbacks exist, but I need to show that all finite limits/colimits exist i.e I also need to show that products and coproducts exist right? How can I do that, an what about Anima (does it fullfill this property or not?)

You know you have both an initial and terminal object. Together with pushouts and pullbacks this gives all finite (co)limits. Also, anima do have all finite (co)limits, but pullback and pushout squares are generally not the same thing: it is not a stable $\infty$-category. Spectra are, though.
